# Recreating a css grid/flexbox image gallery with n rows and columns that are dynamic using react, styled components etc

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, css-grid

I want to try and recreate an image gallery that has a n number of rows based on the number of images from an array but also the columns/images per row can be a single large image, two smaller images or 3 even smaller images. It appears that they are using flexbox and css grid but my brain is rocked trying to figure out how this is done. It almost seems to be generated randomly on what columns are 1, 2 or 3 images wide but it is the same result every time the page is loaded. I am new to css grid and flexbox so how they are generating this layout dynamically based on the number of images is hard to figure out. I am using react, styled-components, css grid, flexbox, etc.

Example image gallery and interactivity showcase:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRjnz.jpg

It appears the grid they are using has 7 columns

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr
```

I assume that the rows are auto generated but it is the columns that are tripping me up.

Each cell or item in the grid can have `grid-column:` starts/ends of either
`1/7` for the large image or
`1/4` then `4/7` for the two side by side images or
`1/3` `3/5` `5/7` for the three side by side images

Anyone know how such an effect can be done dynamically?

Comment: It's not a plain CSS. Better use JS library, like https://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we are talking about a css grid (not vanilla css anyways). Perhaps they are using something like https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout

Where you can define different layouts and switch between them, based on page size

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Could it maybe have been done with bootstrap as well? I think that has the ability to create breakpoints. I am struggling to figure out how they are laying out their grid because it seems almost random but will alter at the breakpoints so that makes me think it isn't a hard coded pattern. In all the resources I've seen it seems like you have to set each row deliberately which is how I am struggling to figure out how they did it to where it can change. Unless it is a custom algorithm they are using.